# Overwrite contents of file in VB

Tags: vba, vbscript

I am reading a list of files and come accross updated versions along the way. In my loop I am checking if the file already exists and trying to remove it, so that I can create the newer version again:

```
objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (objFs.FileExists(location & "\" & fileName & ".xml")) Then
    System.IO.File.Delete(location & "\" & fileName & ".xml")
End If

objTextStream = objFs.CreateTextFile(location & "\" & fileName & ".xml", True)
objTextStream.Write(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recordXml))
```

Ideally I would rather just open the file if it already exists and overwrite the contents, but so far my attempts have been in vein.

`location` is a user defined path, e.g. c://

`recordXML` is a retrieved value from the database

The main error I keep getting is

```
Additional information: Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'.
```

Which seems to mean that the file is either not there to delete, or it is already there when I am trying to create it. The delete may not be working as it should, it may be that the file is not deleted in time to recreate it?..

That's my thoughts anyway.

Comment: vb.net <> vba AndAlso Vb.NET <> vbscript

Comment: Removed VB.NET tag: this is clearly not a .NET question (or if it is: you're doing it wrong).

Comment: Haha OK sorry, I am new to VB..

Answer (score 0):

Found this code at http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/325574-visual-basic-applications-check-if-folder-file-exists-create-them-if-not.html for creating a new file (unless one already exists) and then opening it (existing or new).  Once you open, you can just do a `Sheets(
NAMEOFSHEET").Cells.Clear`to clear the cells and then paste your data.

```
Sub btncontinue_Click()
Dim myFile As String, myFolder As String
myFolder = "C:\TimeCards"
myFile = myFolder & "\timecards.xls"
If Not IsFolderExixts(myFolder) Then
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").CreateFolder myFolder
End If
If Not IsFileExists(myFile) Then
    MsgBox "No such file in the folder"
    Exit Sub
End If
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(myFile)
' Your code here
End Sub

Function IsFolderExists(txt As String) As Boolean
    IsFolderExists = _
        Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FolderExists(txt)
End Function

Function IsFileExists(txt As String) As Boolean
    IsFileExists = _
        CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject").FileExists(txt)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this, it should work in VB, VBA and VBScript.

```
objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If objFs.FileExists(location & "\" & fileName & ".xml") Then Kill(location & "\" & fileName & ".xml")

Open location & "\" & fileName & ".xml" For Output As #1
Print #1, recordXml
Close #1
```

Comment: This could work. Just want to add the _Open File for Output_ method does not work with UTF8 charset. So for example cyrilic and other non standard characters are replaced with _?_

Answer (score 0):

Try to use FSO to delete the file. Also the objTextStream needs to be *set* because it is object.

```
Sub AnySub()
Dim objFs As FileSystemObject
Set objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If (objFs.FileExists(Location & "\" & Filename & ".xml")) Then
    objFs.DeleteFile Location & "\" & Filename & ".xml"
End If
Set objTextStream = objFs.CreateTextFile(Location & "\" & Filename & ".xml", True)

objTextStream.Write recordXml

End Sub
```

I m not sure the .write method work with UTF8.
I m using this function:

```
Sub File_WriteToUTF8(File_Path As String, s_Content As String)
On Error GoTo ende

Dim LineStream As Object
Set LineStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
With LineStream
    .Type = 2
    .Mode = 3
    .Charset = "utf-8"
    .Open
    .WriteTEXT s_Content
    .SaveToFile File_Path, 2
ende:
    .Close
End With
End Sub
```

So instead of

```
objTextStream.Write recordXml
```

it would be

```
File_WriteToUTF8 Location & "\" & Filename & ".xml", recordXml
```

Comment: Thanks, isn't "System.Text.Encoding.UTF8" having the same effect as "File_WriteToUTF8"?

Comment: Could be. I dont use/know system reference library. If it is working for you than I suppose it is OK.